# Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=135; index=-1 al eliminar elemento de recyclerview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, recyclerview

Tengo un problema con el cual no he dado la solución y me ha vuelto loco. He buscado en stackoverflow español e ingles pero no doy con la solución.

Tengo una app donde se agregan todos las imágenes disponibles de una carpeta en especifico en un recyclerview donde se le permite al usuario eliminar imágenes una a una o a través de la selección múltiple. El problema se me presenta cuando se intenta eliminar una a una sin usar la selección múltiple. Esto ocurre de manera aleatoria en diferentes dispositivos, por lo cual se me es algo complicado de reproducir.

Las imágenes se agregan en un `ArrayList` llamado `ListaImagenes` y para eliminar la imagen en la posición seleccionada o correspondiente itero sobre la lista de esta manera:

```java
    File fileToDelete = new File(adaptador.getSimpleItem(position));
                            for (Iterator<String> it = adptador.getImageList().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                                String imgPos = it.next();
                                if (imgPos.equals(adaptador.getSimpleItem(position))) {
                                        it.remove();
                                        adaptador.removeItem(position);
                                        if (fileToDelete.exists()) {
                                            if (fileToDelete.delete()) {
                                                //Muestro un anuncio al usuario notificando que la imagen fué eliminada
                                            }
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }
```

La función `removeItem` y `getSimpleItem` en el adaptador son las siguiente:

```java
     public void removeItem(int position) {
          notifyItemRemoved(position);
          notifyItemRangeChanged(position, ListaImagenes.size());
           
        }
```

```java
     public String getSimpleItem(int position) {
     if (position < ListaImagenes.size()) {
         return ListaImagenes.get(position);
     }else{
         return "";
        } 
}
```

Solución
Gracias a @Andrespengineer por su respuesta.

La solución que me ha funcionado hasta el momento, ya que no se ha vuelto a presentar más este error, es la siguiente:

Antes de acceder a la posición de un elemento hago la siguiente verificación:

```java
public String getSimpleItem(int position) {
if (position < ListaImagenes.size() && position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) { 
//Resto de el código
        } 
}
```

Y además de eso. Ahora he cambiado el método `getAdapterPosition()` por `getBindingAdapterPosition()` ya que el método anterior está obsoleto.

> This method is deprecated. This method is confusing when adapters nest
> other adapters. If you are calling this in the context of an Adapter,
> you probably want to call getBindingAdapterPosition() or if you want
> the position as RecyclerView sees it, you should call
> getAbsoluteAdapterPosition().

Pueden obtener mas información en [este enlace](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition())

Comment: ¿Qué le entregas en `position` cuando defines `fileToDelete`? Como indicas que lo ejecutas desde diferentes lugares, habría que ver qué le llega en cada caso. Lo otro: sería de utilidad incluir un fragmento máaaaas largo de la traza de error. Lo que pusiste en el título da pistas pero ver la traza ayudaría más.

Comment: @Alfabravo Le paso la posición con el método ```getAdapterPosition()``` de recyclerview a través de una interfaz. ```listener.onDeleteItemClicked(getAdapterPosition());``` El log no contiene mucha información me apunta directamente a la función ```getSimpleItem```

Comment: Hola, indica en que linea se produce el error y como obtienes position.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys justo en este línea se me presenta el error. 
`if (position < ListaImagenes.size())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando tienes un RecyclerView concurrido o haces operaciones mientras se esta ejecutando los cálculos del `Layout` correspondientes a la llamada de actualizar los elementos del UI, este siempre te devolvera `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION`. Debes tener en cuenta que si un objeto sufre algun cambio, debes notificar los cambios en el adaptador, para no dejarlo en un estado invalido.

Según la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder?hl=es#getAdapterPosition()) del `RecyclerView`:

> RecyclerView no maneja ninguna actualización del adaptador hasta el
> siguiente recorrido de diseño. Esto puede crear inconsistencias
> temporales entre lo que el usuario ve en la pantalla y el contenido
> del adaptador. Esta inconsistencia no es importante ya que será menos
> de 16 ms, pero podría ser un problema si desea utilizar la posición
> ViewHolder para acceder al adaptador. A veces, es posible que deba
> obtener la posición exacta del adaptador para realizar algunas
> acciones en respuesta a eventos del usuario. En ese caso, debe usar
> este método que calculará la posición del Adaptador de ViewHolder.
>
> Tenga en cuenta que si ha llamado a notifyDataSetChanged (), hasta la
> siguiente pasada de diseño, el valor de retorno de este método será
> NO_POSITION

### Conclusion:

Tienes varias formas de solucionar este problema:

- (Opcional) Implementar [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) o alguna de las clases derivadas para calcular las actualizaciones o sus clases derivadas `ListAdapter` and `AsyncListDiffer`, si tienes calculos o grandes cantidades de elementos. **Debes tener en cuenta que las animaciones por igual tienen un costo**.
- Hacer las validaciones correspondientes a sabiendas de que puedes recibir `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION`. Si implementas DiffUtil, hacer Dispatch de los cambios antes de eliminar el elemento.

Por ejemplo:

```
public void removeItem(int position) {

        if(position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return;

        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, ListaImagenes.size());    
   }
```

- Mover la lógica de eliminado del `Item` dentro del ViewHolder del adaptador y hacer las validaciones correspondientes (`null`, `NO_POSITION`, etc...)

**PD:** Siempre ten en cuenta hacer las validaciones correspondientes para evitar estos tipos de errores, ya que de acuerdo a la misma documentación, este es un caso que se puede dar con ciertas condiciones.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por su respuesta, me ha ayudado mucho. He hecho algunas modificaciones y el error no lo he vuelto a ver mas en producción.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a el error:

> Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=135; index=-1

Tratas de acceder a un elemento con un indice invalido, en este caso el indice tiene valor `-1`

El problema es el valor de `position` , revisa que el valor no sea negativo y sea menor de 134.

Editando...